# Linux iNotify one shot and event mask problem

Tags: linux, filesystems, glibc, inotify

I'm trying to use iNotify in linux rhel5, kernel 2.6.18, glibc 2.5-18. I did not define the event as one shot but for some some reason it behaves as if I did. The impact is that I have to re-add a watch after each event. Any one ever used iNotify? Another problem is that the mask returned in the event object contains only one flag: IN_ONE_SHOT.

Comment: Can you show a small piece of code?

Comment: Try strace.  That's a good way to check that your code is making the system calls you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Write the smallest example you can and test that.  If it demonstrates the behaviour you are talking about then add it to your question.  If it behaves normally then add a little more of your code and test again.  Keep repeating until you have reproduced the error or you have your code working.  Often I find that building a toy program tells me exactly what I am doing wrong that I could not see in a larger program.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that inotify is implicitly deleting the watch because the file is being deleted.  The behaviour is subtly referred to by [the manual page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/inotify.7.html) (see the section on the IN_IGNORED event).  You can check if this is happening by checking if the flag IN_IGNORED is set in the inotify_event populated by your call to `read`.

See also [inotify delete_self when modifying and saving a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754954/inotify-delete-self-when-modifying-and-saving-a-file?rq=1) for why the file may be deleted without your knowledge or action during what you think is just a modification.