# inotify delete_self when modifying and saving a file

Tags: linux, inotify

I am running a small inotify script that sets up a watch on a file. Each time that file is edited and saved, the script notices that a DELETE_SELF event is triggered. Is that normal and if it is why? Shouldn't the inotify subsystem notice that the file still exists?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on what the application that is editing the file is doing with it. In this case, it sounds like the behavior of your editor when it saves a file is to delete the old file and write the new contents as a new file with the same name. From the perspective of inotify, this is exactly what happens, so it fires a deletion event and then a creation event. Inotify cannot know that the file that was deleted and the file that was created in its place are logically related.

Comment: I've tried with vim, gedit and kate - all of them have the same behaviour. You're explanation definitely makes sense, but I am wondering why is implemented this way?

Comment: How it normally works is this: You have a file named `moo.txt` that you're editing. When you save, your editor writes the file to `moo.txt.blah`, then unlinks `moo.txt` then renames `moo.txt.blah` to `moo.txt`.

Comment: Actually, it normally doesn't do the `unlink()` part of that - the `rename('moo.txt.blah', 'moo.txt')` will atomically unlink-and-replace `moo.txt`.  This is *why* editors do it this way - because the operation is atomic, if your editor or system crashes, then you're guaranteed to either see the old file or the new one - not a half-written hybrid.

Comment: Use `ed` (the standard editor) if you don't want the original file being deleted.  :)